# How can I duplicate an HashMap with duplicate values

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I need to create new HashMaps that contain only the duplicate values of my first HashMap :

```
Original map: {Player1=Hello, Player2=Hi, Player3=Hi, Player4=Hello, Player5=Hello}
```

For the outputs, I want to get :

```
Hello map: {Player1=Hello,Player4=Hello, Player5=Hello}
Hi map: {Player2=Hi, Player3=Hi}
```

What is best way to do?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You know about maps apparently, and the simple solution consists in using a map (containing each value of the original map as a key, and the keys as values).

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java8+ you can use stream, with `groupingBy` and `toMap` like so :

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

For e simple map, your outputs can be :

```
Hi - {Player2=Hi, Player3=Hi}
Hello - {Player5=Hello, Player1=Hello, Player4=Hello}
```

[**Ideone demo**](https://ideone.com/nZEEBY)

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Player {
            private String name;
            private int id;

            public Player(int id) {
                this.id = id;
                this.name = "Player " + id;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return this.id;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return this.name;
            }
        }

        Player[] players = new Player[5];
        IntStream.range(0, players.length).forEach(i -> players[i] = new Player(i + 1));

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

        HashMap<Player, String> original = new HashMap<>();
        original.put(players[0], "Hello");
        original.put(players[1], "Hi");
        original.put(players[2], "Hi");
        original.put(players[3], "Hello");
        original.put(players[4], "Hello");

        HashMap<String, HashMap<Player, String>> duplicates = new HashMap<>();

        original.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
            String value = original.get(key);
            HashMap<Player, String> duplicate = duplicates.get(value);

            if (duplicate == null) {
                duplicate = new HashMap<>();

                duplicates.put(value, duplicate);
            }

            duplicate.put(key, value);
        });

        System.out.println("Original: " + original);

        duplicates.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
        });
```

//

```
Original: {Player 1=Hello, Player 2=Hi, Player 3=Hi, Player 4=Hello, Player 5=Hello}
Hi: {Player 2=Hi, Player 3=Hi}
Hello: {Player 1=Hello, Player 4=Hello, Player 5=Hello}
```